# Codeigniter SSL / HTTPS what are my options, multiple sub domains in play.

Tags: php, codeigniter, ssl, https

Recently installed a SSL Cert on our server/domain, and I am realizing now that CI doesn't like `https://` seems like anything that works `http://` gets a 404 in `https://` so but I have some views/controllers that don't require the whole `https://` bit. Such as pages when a user is not logged in to the service I am building up, that are viewable. Only thing I have come up with is configuring the base_url in config.php, which won't work that well for me either, as we have multiple environments where the service runs through before it reaches a public viewable area.

By that I mean we have our dev area where each one of our devs has a separate sub domain with there current dev stack, working on what they are working on. Then we have a staging and QA area, as well as a beta area all before it will reach production.

So I am looking for ideas on how to handle all of this, and short of the base_url config I have no idea where to begin to make this an easy to manage solution.

Comment: Codeigniter has no issues with https:// - I use it all the time on many different projects, as many other people do. The issue is most likely with the configuration of your server or something else

Comment: No, I didn't think it did, however. http:// works fine, if I add the s to it.. then CI throws me a 404.

Comment: Update.. I don't know how to explain it any other way.. but I have since discovered though can't prove it yet that all my https traffic seems to be going directly to my root domain.. so files in my root domain are accessable via the subdomain even if they dont exist to the subdomain, and it doesnt appear to be redirecting back to the main domain either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a DEV, QA, and Production environment for my CodeIgniter site and all of them work fine with HTTPS. No special settings are required for HTTPS to work with it. Perhaps you could provide the URLs your are having trouble with?

Below is how I manage multiple subdomains.

In '/application/config/config.php' set the base_url to auto-detect by leaving it empty:

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

I'm assuming your URLs are:

- http://dev.yourdomain.com
- http://qa.yourdomain.com
- http://youdomain.com

To manage different environments, open index.php in the root directory and add:

```
// This sets the environment based on the subdomain
$domain = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
switch($domain[0])
{
    case 'dev':
        $env = 'dev';
            break;
        case 'qa':
        $env = 'qa';
            break;
    default:
        $env = 'production';
        break;                  
}

define('ENVIRONMENT', $env);

// Error reporting
if (defined('ENVIRONMENT'))
{
    switch (ENVIRONMENT)
    {
        case 'dev':
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
            ini_set("display_errors", 1);
            break;          
        case 'qa':
            case 'production':
            error_reporting(0);
            break;
        case 'production':
            error_reporting(0);
            break;
        default:
            exit('The application environment is not set correctly.');
    }
}
```

If you have a database, setup'/application/config/database.php' to:

```
// Use the respective DB based on the domain name
switch(ENVIRONMENT){
    case 'dev':
        $active_group = 'dev';
        break;
    case 'qa':
        $active_group = 'qa';
        break;
    default:
        $active_group = 'production';
    break;                  
}

// setup domain specific DB's
$db['dev']['hostname'] = 'mysql.stabletransit.com';
// etc..

$db['qa']['hostname'] = 'mysql.stabletransit.com';
// etc..

$db['production']['hostname'] = 'mysql.stabletransit.com';
// etc..
```

Comment: I think by al means, I am going to follow suit with you, I have since found out though the Cert that was installed was one of those "trial" like Certs and only covers the main domain, everything else it seems https related ands up redirecting through the main domain rather than the sub domain, so unless thats a flaw in the configuration, until I get a wild card domain I dont think sub domains will help all to much, in all though this looks like it will help me out on a couple other things. Thank you